# Move the thunderbird notification from bottom panel

Tags: gnome, thunderbird, notification

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and running gnome-shell as primary desktop,I've couple of questions

1) I would like to move the thunder bird notification from bottom right corner to top panel system tray.

2) Notifications are getting piled up in bottom bar I need to click on each item to clear. Say if I get 10 mail then 10 notification Icons are there.

Answer (score 1):

There's a gnome-shell extension that places shell notifications in up right corner.

Use firefox to install it: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/243/shell-osd/

Comment: Nick I've already installed it but still it stays at bottom bar.